# MongoDB fails to connect when multiple hosts are specified in the connection string and one is down

Tags: c#, mongodb, replicaset

I'm using the C# driver to connect to a mongodb replicaset.

The connection string specifies all the hosts that are part of the replicaset:

```
mongodb://host1:2702,host2:2702,host3:2702,host4:2702,host5:2702/myDb
```

I thought that the idea of a replicaset is to stay connective even when a host goes down.. Not just for speed purposes.

Why is the C# driver tries to connect to every one of the hosts specified in the connection string? I'm ok with it checking which of them is the nearest (because I specified Nearest for the ReadConcern) but when it times out, I want it to ignore that host.

Am I missing anything?

Comment: `mongodb://host1:2702,host2:2702,host3:2702,host4:2702,host5:2702/myDb?readPreference=primary` try this one

Comment: You are not specifying the replicaSet as well, mongodb://host1:2702,host2:2702,host3:2702,host4:2702,host5:2702/myDb/?replicaSet=MySet&readPreference=primary

Comment: I tried specifying the `replicaSet` name + `readPreference=primary` and had the same issue. Any other ideas?

Comment: @Jaco you solution worked for me. Except that there is an extra slash after myDb. connection string should read: mongodb://host1:2702,host2:2702,host3:2702,host4:2702,host5:2702/myDb?replicaSet=MySet&readPreference=primary

Answer (score 0):

Your are not specifying the replicaSet for these servers, you can specify it like this:

```
mongodb://host1:2702,host2:2702,host3:2702,host4:2702,host5:2702/myDb?replicaSet=MySet
```